# Colorbox - Prevent parent page reload when removing custom iframe within colorbox content?

Tags: jquery, iframe, append, colorbox

Colorbox provides specific methods for loading an iframe as its content, and when that kind of colorbox popup is closed, the parent page doesn't reload or refresh at all.

However, in my use case, I need to append/add a custom iframe element inside the open colorbox, without swapping the colorbox contents. The already open colorbox content is purely inline HTML - no iframes present whatsoever. The contents of this new custom iframe is a an ajaxified commenting form that only works when loaded as its own page - or in a fully qualified iframe element.

My function that adds the `iframe` below when a link within the colorbox contents is clicked:

```
$('#cboxLoadedContent').append('<IFRAME frameborder="0" src="'+url+'" id="loadednode">');
```

Now I can get that to work no problem - the `IFRAME` gets inserted and goes through the normal loading process for its content and displays everything perfectly.

The only problem is, as soon as I click "out" of this loaded colorbox by using the close button or clicking on the overlay, *unlike exiting colorbox-native iframe contents*, the parent/top page suddenly reloads!

How do I prevent this from happening? What makes the colorbox-native iframes avoid a page refresh when removed, but iframe I've added to colorbox content cause parent page reloads when removed?

For reference, I can load the page that is the content of the iframe as a colorbox-native iframe, and when exited it doesn't cause a page reload, so the problem is not the contents of the iframe in either case - it must be in the way colorbox removes a colorbox-processed iframe vs. a non-colorbox-processed iframe.

Some speculations:

- Does not having a "name" attribute or having a fixed "id" attribute cause issues?
- If the iframe was including in the intial inline HTML without a "src" attribute, but then it gets that "src" path when clicked, will that avoid these problems?
- Is there an alternative way to say "load this iframe in the colorbox I am looking at without removing the HTML contents that are already there"?

I am using (old versions because Drupal 6 is not compatible with newer):

- jQuery 1.3.2
- Colorbox v1.3.18.1 (http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

The initial content opened with colorbox was inline HTML - using colorbox's "inline" command (moving content from a hidden container into the colorbox contents). When a colorbox with this type of content gets closed, the normal behavior for colorbox is to move it back to  its original location (which is a `display: none` div container) - **along with all the HTML I added to the colorbox manually**.

Therefore, when I closed the colorbox after inserting that new HTML into it, colorbox moved all of these contents back to a hidden container on the page from whence it came. And when you move an iframe around, naturally it reloads its content. (Smacks forehead).

So the actual solution simply involves forcibly removing() any iframes that weren't there in the first place, before colorbox goes ahead and returns its HTML content to its original location:

```
$(document).bind('cbox_cleanup', function(){
    $('iframe').remove(); // Remove all iframes, or else colorbox inline moves them to original location with HTML content, triggering another load on it
    console.log('Done killing iFrame... moving contents back.');
```

Obscure use-case I'm sure, but hope it helps someone out there mixing iframe and inline colorbox content ;)

Comment: It's invoked automatically using the $.bind() method. According to the Colorbox docs, `cbox_cleanup` "triggers as the close method begins." So, whenever the "close" operation is triggered (via click on the close button, ESC key, or overlay click), the custom function I have above fires, removing the `iframe` prior to completing the routine cleanup process (which involves moving inline content back to the main page).